# How to give icon value color change in if-else condition in flutter?

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart, flutter-layout

How to change icon color in an if-else statement in flutter

```
Icon(_image == null ? MdiIcons.imageSearch : MdiIcons.checkBold,size: 35)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**You can change color in Icon color parameter
colors : _image == null ?Colors.red : Colors.blue**

```
Icon(_image == null ? MdiIcons.imageSearch : MdiIcons.checkBold,size: 35,color : _image == null ?Colors.red : Colors.blue)
```

Comment: dart 2.12 says Invalid constant value

Comment: @KrunalSonparate maybe there is a const declaration before your Icon, try to remove it and the error will be gone.

Answer (score 0):

use this:

```
Icon(Icons.add , color: _image == null ? Colors.red : Colors.blue,)
```